# Error when attempting to crawl site with python

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler

I am trying to get prices from [this website](https://www.notebooksbilliger.de) for a few monitors. Here is my Code:

```
    def noteBooksBillgerParser(url):
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        while True:
            print ("test")
            sleep(3)
            try:
                doc = html.fromstring(page.content)

                XPATH_PRICE = '//div[@id="product_detail_price"]//content()'
                RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath(XPATH_PRICE)
                PRICE = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_PRICE).split()).strip() if RAW_PRICE else None

                data = {
                    'PRICE': PRICE,
                    'URL': url,
                }

                return data
            except Exception as e:
                print
                e


    def ReadIDs():
        # AsinList = csv.DictReader(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Asinfeed.csv")))
        IDList = ['vp248qg',
                  'vz239he',
                  'vs247hr+164581'
                  ]
        extracted_data = []
        for i in IDList:
            url = "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/asus+" + i
            print("Processing: ", url)
            extracted_data.append(noteBooksBillgerParser(url))
            sleep(2)
        f = open('notebooksbilliger.json', 'w')
        json.dump(extracted_data, f, inde

nt=4)
```

I am pretty sure most of the code is working but i am not sure how to get the Price into my XPATH_PRICE variable. I think there could be a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly getting "Price into my XPATH_PRICE variable", but getting it into your `ROW_PRICE` variable. If your:

```
RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath('//div[@id="product_detail_price"]')[0].values()[4]
```

your output will be (picking, at random `IDList = vz239he`):

```
156.99
```

The rest should then be processed as intended.

Comment: Thanks this should work i guess. But now I have: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.notebooksbilliger.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /asus+vp248qg (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')

Comment: that you wrote  .

Comment: Sure. It's a simplified version of yours (just for one product id): `url = "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/asus+vz239he"   
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}    
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)    doc = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)    XPATH_PRICE = '//div[@id="product_detail_price"]//content()'   RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath('//div[@id="product_detail_price"]')[0].values()[4]`

Comment: thats okay. Can you post it in a comment?

Comment: sorry, one typo: the `XPATH_PRICE = '//div[@id="product_detail_price"]//content()'` line needs to be deleted from my previous comment (can't edit that one anymore...)

Comment: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)

Comment: No errors on my side; but remember, I just tried one product so no 'max retries' on my part.

Comment: okay im getting this wiith yours version anyway but it still helped me. Your done with this question for now :P

Comment: i found the error. I had problems with my SSL certificates :P

Comment: dude pls helpo hilpo me i have now error: RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath('//div[@id="product_detail_price"]')[0].values()[4]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: by just copying ur text and removing xpath line

Comment: i hope you see my comment  @Jack Fleeting